# Unable to open android studio project created in windows to other OS- Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, android-studio

Searched solution on internet but for the solution to follow compiler (gradle) in settings need to be accessed. But, its not on the list, as seen in the screenshot. May be because it is Ubuntu this difference arises. I am a beginner in Ubuntu as well as Android Studio. Please help.

[image: image of settings menu of compiler]
[image: image showing error]

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at 

Please read below process output to find out more:
-----------------------
/home/r/android-studio/jre/bin/java: 9: /home/r/android-studio/jre/bin/java: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Comment: Check these StackOverflow threads [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471311/android-studio-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio)

Comment: Thank u for your kind response...but these solutions are for windows, the first link says delete gradle file from C drive, which is not there in Ubuntu...the second link about vm options, the snapshot I have uploaded is for the same reason that I have no such option as "vm"

Comment: 12.04 was on-topic when this was written. grandfather clause, leave open.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the problem Gradle cache. So you need to delete `.gradle` folder from your home directory. To do that follow these steps.

1. Browse to this path

   ```
   /home/your_user_name/
   ```
2. By default `.gradle` directory is hidden. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>. Now this will show you all the hidden directories and files.
3. Delete `.gradle` directory and restart your Android Studio.
4. If the above steps don't work you also need to delete `.android` directory which is in the same path of `.gradle`. And restart Android Studio.
5. Or another way is to follow these steps in Android Studio

   ```
   File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart -> select -> Invalidate and Restart
   ```

Source: [Android Studio: Unable to start the daemon process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20471311/5180017)